# Oddity in my markdown document, does anyone else see this?

Tags: markdown

[Check out this readme](https://github.com/maurymarkowitz/RetroBASIC/blob/master/README.md) and scroll down to the section about command-line switches. On my display, `--random` displays on the end of the `--goto-next` text. I can't figure out why. I looked in the source and there don't appear to be any hidden characters, and as far as I can tell those lines are identical to the ones above and below it. Does anyone else see this, or is it a browser issue?

Comment: Full Screenshot in Edge on Windows : https://i.postimg.cc/gJdGQ8Xd/image.png

Comment: To start a new line, you need two spaces at the end, the line in question has none. Add the spaces and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation

This is due to the fact that all the other lines have two whitespaces at their ends, except for the one that starts with `--goto-next`. Generally speaking though, this is also a correct way of spacing out your lines, but it's less visible and more prone to these kinds of errors.
As an example, open my answer in raw mode and see that I'm writing in a new line while not going two lines below.

### Code snippets

Here's a code snippet:

> (highlight the code with your cursor to see the spaces)

```markdown
This is how you normally start a new line.

After two consecutive line breaks. But you can also achieve a line break with two tailing spaces at the line's end.
```

### Better practices

It's usually better to use bulleted lists or tables, they'll get formatted nicely are also are visible in the raw text file as well. After all, MarkDown was designed to be readable, both in raw and rendered modes.

### Edit: HTML no-bullet lists

You can achieve lists with no bullet by inserting HTML+CSS into your document as below:

```
Other command-line options include:

<ul style="list-style-type: none;">
   <li>
   
   `--help`, `-h`: print usage notes
   
   </li>
   <li>
   
`--version`, `-v`: print version info

   </li>
   <li>
   
`--upper-case`, `-u`: force input to upper-case, basically like using caps lock

   </li>
   <li>
   
`--array-base`, `-a`: set base index for arrays, normally 1 but some dialects use 0

   </li>
   <li>
   
`--tabs`, `-t`: set the number of spaces for comma-separated items, defaults to 10

   </li>
   <li>
   
`--goto-next`, `-g`: if a branch targets a non-existant line, should it go to the next line? normally false

   </li>
   <li>
   
`--random`, `-r`: seed the random number generator

   </li>
   <li>
   
`--output-file`, `-o`: redirect PRINT to the named file

   </li>
   <li>
   
`--input-file`, `-i`: redirect INPUT from the named file, one INPUT value per line

   </li>
</ul>
```

> **Notes**:
>
> 1. It is messy, and really tedious to do this by hand.
> 2. Your styles will get overwritten by GitHub and the bullets will appear again.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason my editor is not showing the second whitespace. I'll add it. The reason I didn't use a list marker is that I thought a number or bullet at the front might be confusing. Is there a way to make a list with a blank as the bullet?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz You technically can, however you'd need to put HTML in your markdown file and then style it with in-line CSS. More specifically, you'll need a `ul` with 9 `li` tags inside of it, and you'd also need to set the style of this list to no-bullet with `none`. However, in your case it's not useful because of GitHub, and I really don't suggest doing it. I edited my answer to include this in more details as well.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I believe the text is legible with bulleted lists. You could also go for tables which look really neat.